# Java program to copy file based on user input

Tags: java

A user enters in a source file and a destination file and that file will be copied. I'm running into an IO error and I'm not sure where it's coming from. If I were to print out fileA or fileB I get the correct file address so I'm not sure how to debug this.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Copy {

  public Copy(String name) {
    f(name);
  }

  private void f(String name) {
    String[] files = name.split(" ");
    File fileA = new File(files[0]);
    File fileB = new File(files[1]);

    if (name == "") {
      System.out.println("Please specify FileA path and FileB path");
    } else if (files.length == 1) {
      System.out.println("Please specify two files and their paths");
    } else if (!fileA.exists()) {
      System.out.println("FileA does not exist");
    } else if (fileB.exists()) {
      System.out.println("File already exists");
    } else if (fileA.isDirectory()) {
      System.out.println("FileA is a directory - needs to be a file");
    } else {
      try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileA);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileB);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {

          fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: You need to catch `IOException` in addition to `FileNotFoundException` for this to compile. If this is not a learning assignment, you could just use `java.nio.File.copy()`

Comment: changing the catch exception worked, thank you!